# How do auto import butterkniffe in all my new Android Studio projects?

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

It is tedious to have to add libraries to use in all my projects . Is there any way to make Android Studio add all dependencies that I frequently use?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a plugin which does all that work for you. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html for more details